# Keep a function active in background on the server

Tags: .net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, recursion

I’m working on a mvc application over .Net, an extended part of it contains a function that post things to different social networking platforms such as Facebook, twitter etc. in a nutshell what it does is it actually automatically posts over different network after an specified interval and on specified timings. The problem is that the posting part has to be always running anonymously in the background without any connection to the state of real website, so it could keep checking the time/interval and posts whenever required.

Currently my controller has a recursive function that in main part looks like below code, But just as it happened in mvc this functions gets initiates through an url call from a client browser, and after the call the browser goes on waiting state because this function keeps running recursively until browser cancels the request after an specified no respond time.

Of course this behavior is not ideal, so what I want is to:

- Make this function independent and it keeps running in the background
  on server continuously.
- Someone told me that if I work though using WCF (Windows communication foundation) making it a service etc. it would solve me problem? I don’t WCF yet but if can solve the problem I can give it a try.
- Any other ways I can achieve this?

*Code:*

```
    while (status == "1")
        {

            if (totalRows > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i < totalRows; i++)
                {
                    myPostArray[i] = myPosts.Tables["myPosts"].Rows[i]["Postmsg"].ToString();
    //…
    //Post to the platform through respected API
    //…

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000000000);
                }
                status = true;
            } else if (myPosts.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                status = false;
            }
            TheRepeater();
```

Comment: I would argue that this sort of thing isn't appropriate for a web application..

Comment: @Simon Whitehead: what do you suggest as an alternative? this functionality doesn't requires to be a part of the web app.. it can also run totally separate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a separate service for this which will do the following:

- Accept a "start the processing" command from your web application
- Return "acknowledged, will start processing now" - this will end the communication between your web app and the service, releasing the communication channel and returning the control back to web server (instead of timing out)
- Do the background processing in your service, potentially doing a `sleep` at the end of a cycle to auto-wake-up for next iteration

Comment: Thankyou for replying.. But in my understanding in a mvc application `acknowledged, will start processing now` command can be returned through returning something from a function most probably a view and after a return has been called from a function it means it has completed executing, how can it keep itself running thn?

Comment: @Maven - because it's a separate thread running in the service!  The web server in the service merely starts it and, in the HTTP response, gets an acknowledgement that it has started.  The service thread/s then do your processing stuff in a loop.

Comment: Martin is correct - you are free to return an `ACK` whenever you are pleased, that doesn't make your code "lose focus" or get killed

Comment: Pardon my ignorance ppl, but I am still unable to understand how to send back the `Acknowledgment`... what do you exactly mean by this, how do I send it back, send it through `return` statement isn’t going to end the function?

Comment: In this context "send" means "send a signal back to the caller". The caller is **not** the same process, so a mere `return` statement doesn't have much to do with that. Probably you need to read up a little on IPC (inter-process communications) and/or RPC (remote procedure calls).